# How to programatically close a matplotlib window?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have implemented a ROI selection function that spawns a matplolib window. Once the selection is done, I want to close this function and continue with the rest of my code. At the end of the selection, the rest of the code runs fine but the window is never closed.

I have tried three methods to close the window:

```py
plt.close('all')
```

```py
self.fm = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
self.fm.destroy()
```

```py
plt.show(block=False)
```

but neither of them closes the window.

Here is a working example of the selector class:

```py
class RectangleSelection(object):
    def __init__(self, img):
        self.rectangle = None
        self.img = img
        self.done = False

        #Setup the figure
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.fm = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
        plt.ion
        plt.imshow(self.img, cmap='gray')

        self.RS = RectangleSelector(self.ax, self.onselect,
                                       drawtype='box', useblit=True,
                                       button=[1, 3],  
                                       minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                                       spancoords='pixels',
                                       interactive=True)

        plt.connect('key_press_event', self.toggle_selector)
        plt.show()

    def onselect(self, e_click, e_release):
        # [...] do stuff

    def toggle_selector(self, event):
        if event.key in ['Q', 'q'] and self.RS.active:
            self.RS.set_active(False)
            self.done = True

    def close(self):
        logging.debug("Closing selection window")
        plt.show(block=False)
        plt.close('all')
        self.fm.destroy()
```

and the calling function

```py
selector = RectangleSelection(img)
while not selector.done:
    pass
crop_box = selector.rectangle
logging.debug("Got crop_box %s", str(crop_box))
selector.close() # I want the window to close at this point
plt.pause(0.5)

long_process(crop_box)
# The window eventually closes when the process completely finishes.
```

`selector.close()` is called (as shown by a logging message) but it does not result in the window being closed.

A shorter working example in an ipython prompt is the following:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.ion()
plt.plot([1.6, 2.7]) # This shows the plot in a window
plt.title("Test Title") # This works showing the link between code and plot is there
plt.clf() # This works too, clearing the figure
plt.close() # This makes the plot window unresponsive but does not close it.
```

Comment: You want to press the `q` key to close the window? That is the default already, so I don't think I understand the problem.

Comment: Indeed, because `q` is the default, I can remove all the key binding processing code and the selector still works, however, the window doesn't close until the calling process has completely finished executing (which can take a long time).

Comment: What environment are you running this in? jupyter, IDLE on Windows, command line with Gnome, ...? It might be relevant.

Comment: The code is part of a command line interface so I am using the default backend for matplotlib of the OS the code runs on. As of now I am running this on macos.

Comment: I checked and the backend is TkAgg right now. I added a shorter working example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the comments. It looks like it might be a bug in the Tkinter backend. Switching to the Qt4Agg backend results in the expected behavior where plt.close() closes the window as expected.